# How can I use setting values in launch config property values in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VS Code extension where I need the launch.json configuration/program variable point to an extension setting. Is this possible?

I tried to use environment variables but without success.

I think to use a JavaScript to read the extension setting and pass it to the launch.json "configuration/program" variable.

Comment: Related: [Use VS Code extension variable in task.json](/q/63711174/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [configuration variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_configuration-variables), which are of the form `${config:<settingName>}`. Ex. `${config:editor.fontSize}`.